# bash Split string to array

Tags: arrays, bash

How to split

`"DB-ConnString","Server=tcp:database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=db;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=DATAFACTORY;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;Authentication='Identity';"`

to an array?

`IFS="," read -r -a my_array <<< "$line"` doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: it looks like you want split the string based on a comma but you appear to have a comma as part of the data in the `"Server..."` portion; how many elements are you expecting in the array? 2 or 3?  do you also want to split on `;`? it would help if you update the question with what you expect the array contents to look like

Comment: Strings can be split in thousands of ways. You need to explain how you want it split.

Comment: comma is the delimiter. key being "DB-ConnString", value is the rest of it - "Server=tcp:database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=db;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=DATAFACTORY;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;Authentication='Identity';"

Comment: I'd suggest using perl or python or another language with a real CSV parser available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reset your delimiter to something not embedded in your data.

```
$: echo "$line"
"DB-ConnString","Server=tcp:database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=db;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=DATAFACTORY;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;Authentication='Identity';"

$: IFS="|" read -r -a my_array <<< "${line//\",\"/\"\|\"}" # change "," to "|"
$: printf "[%s]\n" "${my_array[@]}"                        # show the results
["DB-ConnString"]
["Server=tcp:database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=db;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=DATAFACTORY;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;Authentication='Identity';"]
```